# PyQt5 GUI only updates when screen is clicked off and back on

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am running into an issue when I am taking in values over serial and then attempting to update my Gui with those values. Unfortunately, even though the values update correctly, I am unable to get to the screen to refresh unless I click off of it and then back on to it. I have tried repaint, update, and processEvents() but have been unable to solve the problem.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
import sys
import serial
import time
import requests


import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import mainwindow_auto


CUSTOM_EVENT = 1000
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
class TestThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, target):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.target = target

    def run(self):
        while True:
            QApplication.postEvent(self.target, QEvent(QEvent.Type(CUSTOM_EVENT)))
            QApplication.processEvents()
            QThread.sleep(15)




class MainWindow(QMainWindow, mainwindow_auto.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)# gets defined in the UI file
        self.thread = TestThread(self)
        self.thread.start()

    def event(s, e):
        if(e.type() == CUSTOM_EVENT):
            print("Readline: ",int(ser.readline()))
            SOC = int(ser.readline())
            s.lcdNumber.display(SOC)
            s.progressBar.setValue(SOC)
            print("SOC: ",SOC)
            print(s.lcdNumber.value())

        return True


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.lcdNumber.display(30)
    form.progressBar.setValue(30)
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an I/O thread, let it handle the I/O and sent the received value to the main thread via a signal.

No need for a custom event, no I/O on the main thread.
Just adding a signal to the thread subclass and connecting a slot to that before starting the thread.

Comment: Hi Kevin! Thanks for your quick response! I tried to go the route you suggested but ended up with lots of debugging (first time using PyQt). I ended up solving it with a force redraw by hiding and reshowing the screen. May not be best practice but it has been stable thus far. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rewriting the code that I had above, I ended up fixing it by force redrawing using s.hide() and s.show() after updating the values in the event code. It forced a redraw that otherwise refused to work.

```
s.lcdNumber.display(SOC)
s.progressBar.setValue(SOC)
s.hide()
s.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @KevinKrammer, this is simple to do with a custom signal:

```
class TestThread(QThread):
    serialUpdate = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            QThread.sleep(1)
            value = int(ser.readline())
            self.serialUpdate.emit(value)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, mainwindow_auto.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.thread = TestThread(self)
        self.thread.serialUpdate.connect(self.handleSerialUpdate)
        self.thread.start()

    def handleSerialUpdate(self, value):
        print("Readline: ", value)
        self.lcdNumber.display(value)
        self.progressBar.setValue(value)
```